# Populate checkbox list using angularjs on server response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am new to angular js .
This is my html code where I am binding list of recipients comming from sql table to checkbox using angular js ng-repeat.(data is comming from db) on my form.
User select the recipient(s) and when click submit button and that info is save into database which is working fine.

```
 <div class="md-checkbox contactsChecked" ng-repeat="item in chooseInternalContacts">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id={{item.InternalContactId}} ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="internalContact==1" @*ng-checked="item.sbc.count > 0 ? true : false"*@ class="md-check" value="{{item.InternalContactId}}" data-ng-model="internalContact">
                                            <label for={{item.InternalContactId}}>
                                                <span></span>
                                                <span class="check"></span>
                                                <span class="box"></span> {{item.EmailAddress}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
```

```html
 <div class="md-checkbox contactsChecked" ng-repeat="item in chooseInternalContacts">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id={{item.InternalContactId}} ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="internalContact==1" @*ng-checked="item.sbc.count > 0 ? true : false"*@ class="md-check" value="{{item.InternalContactId}}" data-ng-model="internalContact">
                                                <label for={{item.InternalContactId}}>
                                                    <span></span>
                                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                                    <span class="box"></span> {{item.EmailAddress}}
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
```

My Angular Js Code and it holds the list of recipients.

```
studs.data.NotificationItemExtendedRecipients[i].InternalContact
```

I am using same form for edit record so when user click edit I want to show the recipients of that row "Checked" and rest "Unchecked"
How to achieve this I am new to angular js.

Comment: Can you see in console any error. Did you check whether values are binding in `chooseInternalContacts`

Comment: Yes values are binding. Its fine. but I dont know how to show checked. As I said recipients comming from separate table binding it with checkbox and when user select  one or two checkbox it save the data in different table.This is working fine. All I need to know how to show checkbox checked when I want to edit the data on same form.

Comment: Are you seeing any error in Console ? In that code snippet, it showing {{item.EmailAddress}}. which means, angularjs is not affecting for the block. I see you commented something in input tag. Can you remove that comment and try.

Comment: There is no error in console. ignore that commented part. {{item.EmailAddress}} is showing the email address as a display text for the checkbox.

Comment: In that `ng-checked="true"`, then that check-box displays as checked. Can you try to give some condition which data needs to checked based on DB values.